# How do I manually add an installer in a windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I wrote an abstract class "PollingServiceBase" that inherits from ServiceBase in order to write windows service that had an override method Work that executes on a timer declared in the constructor. So I'm trying test it and I wrote a quick little class that writes a line including the datetime to a text file every minute. I need to install this service, but when i can't use the designer to "Add Installer" because PollingServiceBase is abstract. So can anyone either give me a workaround or point me to a resource that shows me how to do this manually?

Comment: You know you can install it from command line, like this: `sc create MyServiceName binPath= c:\MyServiceDirectory\MyExe.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new one in your service by code:

```
ServiceInstaller installer = new ServiceInstaller();
```

And make sure that you use the properties correctly.

For an easier way, I recommend looking at the TopShelf. It's a nice library to write a Windows Service and make it runnable through F5. Basically, it's a console application.

Here's some information on TopShelf:

http://topshelf-project.com/

If you still want to stick with the basic implementation, here's some code:

```
using (TransactedInstaller installer = new TransactedInstaller())
{
    string path = string.Format("/assemblypath={0}",
                  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    string[] arguments = { path };
    InstallContext context = new InstallContext("", arguments);

    using (ProjectInstaller projectInstaller = new ProjectInstaller())
    {
        installer.Installers.Add(projectInstaller);
    }

    installer.Context = context;
    installer.Install(new Hashtable());
}
```

Comment: First, I love the idea of TopShelf. I could have used that a few months ago. I guess my problem with it for my current situation is that it seems like a band-aid fix. I'll need for people to be able to install their own services that inherit from my PollingServiceBase. I'm looking at the code you posted, and I hope you'll forgive my unfamiliarity with the subject matter, but where would I implement that? In my service, in the base class, or in the program.cs file in the service?

Comment: In my project it's in the startup of the application. Basiccly it's a console application and when the first command line argument is "/install" the code above is running. I dont' know your situation, but I think each of your cliënts that will inherit from your base class needs to use this code. But you can embed in your base class and let users just call it from in their program. If it's not clear, just ask :-)